# Running a command with arguments assistance

Tags: powershell, command

I have a command which runs a program in silent mode, it uses an XML file for the data repository and a word template to create multiple word documents based on a filter xml file.

The command I use is:

```
"P:\ath to\executable" -Username:Admin -Password:Pa55w0rd -Datadefinition:"C:\Data.xml" -Datafilter:"C:\Filter.xml" -wordtemplate:"C:\Batch\Paul1.dotx" -Targetdocument:="C:\Batch\Paul1.pdf" -filetype:PDF -Log:"C:\Logs\error.log"  -Usage:DOCGENSILENT
```

I need to run this as a PowerShell script which I have mostly managed:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted  

$datadefinition = Get-Content "C:\Data file.xml"
$datafilter = Get-Content "C:\Filter for data file.xml"
$wordTemplate = Get-Content "C:\"C:\Template\Paul1.dotx"
$targetFolder = Get-Content "C:\"C:\Paul\Paul.pdf"

Stop-Job = "Executable path" -Username:Admin -Password:Pa55w0rd -Datadefinition:%dataDefinition% -Datafilter:%dataFilter% -wordtemplate:%wordTemplate% -Targetdocument:%targetFolder% -filetype:docx -Log:%logPath%  -Usage:DOCGENSILENT 

Stop-Job 1

set-executionpolicy restricted  

Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

My issue is that the script starts the executable but then doesnt pass the Variables, can anyone guide me in the right direction to fix this?

Comment: `set targetFolder=..` sets a path to a file. `$datadefinition = Get-Content` however gets the first line as content from the file. Then you seem to use the `batch-file` variables still in the powershell script? `%dataFilter%`

Comment: So get rid of `Get-Content` and just set the variables to `$datadefinition = "C:\Data file.xml"` etc. change your variables in the executable path to `$dataDefinition` instead of `%dataDefinition%`. Also, what is the purpose of `Stop-Job` I am not seeing any relationship with that with what is in the batch file? Lastly, your `batch-file` as it currently is, overwrites 2 of your variables. `wordTemplate` and `targetFolder` will both end up with `Paul1.*` only.

Comment: Your question is technically about running a command with parameters/arguments from PowerShell, batch files and file conversion is irrelevant to your question. I have therefore removed your references to [tag:batch-file], and [tag:file-conversion]. In addition I've removed the batch file content and provided just the command line the batch file was running. In addition, there are two errors in your path strings, `"C:\"C:\Template\Paul1.dotx"`, should be `"C:\Template\Paul1.dotx"`, and `"C:\"C:\Paul\Paul.pdf"`, should be `"C:\Paul\Paul.pdf"`.

Comment: What is `Stop-Job = ` supposed to do? I doubt very much that it will start an executable file with arguments. Perhaps you want to look at using `&` or `start-process` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Getting this working depends on the behavior of your executable. Some things I noticed:

1. Shouldn't this:

   ```
   $wordTemplate = Get-Content "C:\"C:\Template\Paul1.dotx"
   ```

   be this:

   ```
   $wordTemplate = "C:\Template\Paul1.dotx"
   ```

   Are you sure you need `Get-Content`? (Aside from that, the path and quoting in your sample are not correct.)
2. Shouldn't this:

   ```
   $targetFolder = Get-Content "C:\"C:\Paul\Paul.pdf"
   ```

   be this:

   ```
   $targetDocument = "C:\Paul\Paul.pdf"
   ```

   I doubt `Get-Content` is correct here, since presumably your output file doesn't exist yet? I also renamed the variable so it makes more sense in your command.
3. In fact, are you sure you need `Get-Content` for any of those? Aren't you specifying filenames, not the *content* of the files?
4. In PowerShell, variables are prefixed with `$` rather than being surrounded by `%`.
5. Using `Set-ExecutionPolicy` *within* a script to enable scripts to run is pointless, because the script is already running. (That is, if execution policy prevented script execution, PowerShell wouldn't let you run the script in the first place.)

If my guesses regarding your variables are correct, I think your script should look something like this (note also that I specified a `$logFile` variable, which I didn't see in your script):

```
$datadefinition = "C:\Users\Administrator\data\Sample Model_146_object type(s).xml"
$datafilter = "C:\Users\Administrator\data\Sample Model_146_object type(s).xml"
$wordtemplate = "C:\Users\Administrator\Templates\Base object.docx"
$targetdocument = "C:\Users\Administrator\Result\sample test15"
$logfile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Logs\C4W Error.log"

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Communicator4Word.exe" -Username:Admin -Password: -Datadefinition:$datadefinition -Datafilter:$datafilter -wordtemplate:$wordtemplate -Targetdocument:$targetdocument -filetype:docx -Log:$logfile -Usage:DOCGENSILENT
```

I don't know the behavior of `Communicator4Word.exe` when you use `-Password:` with no password after it. (Is that a syntax error, or should you just omit `-Password:` altogether?)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am litterally just learning powershell, us old dogs dont like to change our ways unfortunately for me Company policy has changed and MD wants us to stop using Batch and Com scripts, powershell looks easier to convert to than css or vscript, I will test your suggestions and let you know how i get on

Comment: Quick update, if i set the command to & "P:\ath to\executable" the executable program starts, once I add the hyphen after the executable it errors

Comment: Here is the error i am getting, i have removed the username and password as the script is running with logged in user.
At line:16 char:1
+ -Datadefinition:$datadefinition -Targetdocument:$targetdocument 
-wordtemplate:$w ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Datadefinition::String) [], Co 
   mmandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Please update your question with a copy and paste of the _exact_ script you are running as well as a copy and paste of the _full and complete_ error message(s) you are getting. (Remember, we can't see your screen!)

Comment: Ok here is my script in entirety:

Comment: Script to big to paste in 1 go, here are the variables:  $path - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Communicator4Word.exe"
$datadefinition ="C:\Users\Administrator\data\Sample Model_146_object type(s).xml"
$datafilter ="C:\Users\Administrator\data\Sample Model_146_object type(s).xml"
$wordTemplate ="C:\Users\Administrator\Templates\Base object.docx"
$targetdocument ="C:\Users\Administrator\Result\sample test15"
$logfile ="C:\Users\Administrator\Logs\C4W Error.log"

Comment: Here is the command: & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Communicator4Word.exe" -Username:Admin -Password: -Datadefinition:$datadefinition -Datafilter:$datafilter -wordtemplate:$wordTemplate -Targetdocument:$targetdocument -filetype:docx -Log:%logPath%  -Usage:DOCGENSILENT

Comment: No error message is coming up, the error previously was down to the command Write-Host -NoNewLine "Press any key to continue..."
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") but this was only added to stop on an error, removed it but the script runs but i get no output, really confusing

Comment: Don't paste in the comments. Please update your _question_ with the script (using 4-space indent, so we can clearly see the code).